# Unable to Print Log

Tags: magento2.4.1, logging

Hi i am trying to print log here but its not working

**file path is :- Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Shipping\Rate\Result\GetAllRates.php**

```
class GetAllRates
    {
        public function afterGetAllRates($subject, $result)
        {
            $writer = new \Leminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/logfile.log');
            $logger = new \Leminas\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info('Simple Text Log');
    
            foreach ($result as $key => $rate) {
                // $mymethod = $rate->getCarrier();
        
            }
            return $result;
            
        }
    }
```

can anyone suggest the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use it like-

```
use Zend\Log\Logger;
use Zend\Log\Writer\Stream;
 
public function afterGetAllRates($subject, $result)
    {
        $outputFileName = BP."/var/log/logfile.log";        
        $fw = fopen ( $outputFileName, 'w' );
        fwrite ( $fw, "TEST FROM OBSERVER\n\n" );
        fclose ( $fw );
    }
```

If this creates your file then you can input any parameter and make it write in the log file.

Thanks,
Rashi

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :-**

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/logfile.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Simple Text Log');
```